# How to group concat and sum (unpredictable) values in a pivot table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a pivot table like (note that the keys are known, but not the value each of them will store, dates for instance):

```
      ID              Reference          Key               Value
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    01                  001             date                03/04/2009
    02                  001             shift               1st
    03                  001             station a           Mark
    04                  001             station b           John
    05                  001             station b           Macy
    06                  002             date                04/04/2009
    07                  002             shift               2nd
    08                  002             station a           John
    09                  002             Station a           Drey
    10                  002             Station b           Macy
```

And i would like to have:

```
    Operator         Dates             1st Shift    2nd shift   A Station  B Station
    ---------+-----------------------+------------+------------+----------+--------
    Mark      03/04/2009                   2              0           1        0
    John      03/04/2009, 04/04/2013       1              1           1        1
    Macy      03/04/2009, 04/04/2009       1              1           0        2
    Drey      04/04/2009                   0              1           1        0
```

In other words: "Dates" column show the days each employ worked. The other columns count the number of times each employee worked at each station and on each shift.

It would also be great if query could be fit in a view....

Tx a lot!
Maybe it could be something related to:

```
    SET @sql = NULL; 
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'SUM(IF(tblColumn = ''', tblColumn, ''', 1, 0)) AS ', tblColumn ) ) 
    INTO @sql FROM Table1; SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM Table1'); 
    PREPARE stmt 
    FROM @sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select name, group_concat(d.value separator ', ') as dates,
       sum(s.value = '1st') as FirstShift,
       sum(s.value = '2nd') as SecondShift,
       sum(n.key = 'station a') as StationA,
       sum(n.key = 'station b') as StationB
from (select value as name, key, reference
      from table t
      where key in ('station a', 'station b')
     ) n join
     table d
     on n.reference = d.reference and d.key = 'date' join
     table s
     on n.reference = s.reference and s.key = 'shift'
group by name;
```

Comment: Tx @Gordon. I'll check it asap!

Comment: The problem is that the values stored in the collumn "value" are not predictable. So i could have station zz or shift k and so on.

Comment: I found something interesting, bit cant adapt to my needs... Added to the question. At the end

Comment: @user3697932 . . . A SQL query has predefined columns, so you can only do what you want using dynamic SQL.